# C# Console App - Streamwriter overwriting CSV file every time it writes new "Page" from API call, only leaving last API call results

Tags: c#, csv, console-application, streamwriter

So, I KNOW this is a simple thing but I typically work with ASP.NET web apps and SQL, so I'm having a problem with this console app.

I have a console app that pulls a "page" of data from a webclient API call. This pulls the data into a string (s) and writes that data to a CSV file. The method then loops, incrementing the "pagenum" by +1  until the API returns the string "No records found".

My problem is, instead of appending each new "page" of data to the existing CSV file, it overwrites the file with the previous "page" of data. So, I write page 1, then get page 2, and all the data in the CSV is replaced with Page 2 data, rinse and repeat.

My question: do I need to create a new "string" for each page of data (maybe incrementing the string variable name by 1 (s1, s2, s3) based on page number or do I simply need to change my loops to use some sort of other part of Streamwriter (like is there an add line command I need to call at the end of the loop?) If so, any ideas on how to do this based on my sample code below? (NOTE: I have some Console.WriteLines for debugging purposes so I can see the data while testing.)

```
while (!s.Contains("No records found")) //When API returns "No Records Found" we know we've reached the last page of data we need to get.
        {
            rpcURL = "https://api.WEBSITEcom/urlrpc?method=getPlacementReport&username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&class_code=" + classCode + "&from_date=" + startDate + "&to_date=" + endDate + "&page_num=" + page;
            Console.WriteLine(rpcURL);
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(rpcURL))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                s = sr.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(s);
                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                string docPath = path + "\\" + "AleksReport.csv";


                if (!s.Contains("No records found"))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(docPath))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("End of records");
                }
            }
            page++;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a second argument to `StreamWriter`, which indicates whether or not you want to *append* to the file. Here, obviously you want `true`:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(docPath, true))
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_)

However, I think a better way is to not create a stream writer every iteration of the loop. Create one stream writer and reuse it:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string docPath = path + "\\" + "AleksReport.csv";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(docPath)) {
    while (!s.Contains("No records found")) //When API returns "No Records Found" we know we've reached the last page of data we need to get.
    {
        rpcURL = "https://api.WEBSITEcom/urlrpc?method=getPlacementReport&username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&class_code=" + classCode + "&from_date=" + startDate + "&to_date=" + endDate + "&page_num=" + page;
        Console.WriteLine(rpcURL);
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(rpcURL))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            s = sr.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(s);

            if (!s.Contains("No records found"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(s);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of records");
            }
        }
        page++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this constructor `public StreamWriter (string path, bool append);` with second param set to true. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_).

> append
>
> true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect,
>   and the constructor creates a new file.